# How to make RabbitMQ scalable?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, load-balancing, scalability

I tried to test RabbitMQ, but I found that rabbitmq has some problems:
if I created a cluster of 3 nodes, I can't publish/delivered more than 6000/s.
in other hand, if I worked with one single node, I can publish/delivery until 25000/s.
which means, more that I add nodes, more performance is deteriorating.

but from this article : https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/products/rabbitmq-hits-one-million-messages-per-second-on-google-compute-engine

they can publish more than 1 million, so how they can do that?
I want to make RabbitMQ process more than 1 million messages per second

Comment: Are you consuming these messages, or only publishing?

Comment: I have an efficient consumer, and many producers, but the producer can send more than 900000 messages per second. The problem is that Rabbitmq can't process more than 22000messages/seconds (in single node), but if I used a cluster (for fault-tolerance issues), the performance deteriorating,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the problem by adding load balancer.
The producers send data to load balancer. On the other hand the load balancer id connected to many nodes of rabbitmq, but those nodes are not connected between them (to avoid synchronization which affects the performance).
So by this way, I can multiply the throughput (ex: 3 nodes= 3x throughput).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you subscribe to multiple nodes in this case ?(again via load balancer or some other strategy)

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on other factors such as your network, or your hardware performance.

**When reading benchmark always consider the environment surrounding the tests**

As on how to improve perf you can improve your hardware or network if this is the limiting factor.

Consider switching to a SSD or using link aggregation on your network would be a good start.

Comment: this is not the problem. In that benchmarking test, they used a cluster with 32 machines, but if I tried the same thing,I will not even able to process more than 10 messages/second, because, for each added node, the performance becomes worse

Answer (score 0):

In [this test of RabbitMQ performance](https://people.cs.vt.edu/butta/cs4284/spring2011/butta/RabbitMQPaper.pdf), the authors concluded that a small cluster will underperform a single node cluster. More nodes need to be added to increase the performance. This makes sense when you think about the overhead induced by replication required in a distributed system, especially given that RabbitMQ focus is reliability.

The following is mentioned in a [blog post by RabbitMQ](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2020/06/cluster-sizing-and-other-considerations):

> If you use quorum queues or mirrored queues, then each message will be delivered to multiple brokers. If you have a cluster of three brokers and quorum queues with a replicator factor of 3, then every broker will receive every message. In that case, we’ve created a cluster *for redundancy only*. But we can also create larger clusters *for scalability*. We could have a cluster of 9 brokers, with quorum queues with a rep factor of 3 and now we’ve spread that load out and can handle a much larger total throughput.