# Is RabbitMQ Clustering including scalability too?

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, scalability

I want to build a RabbitMQ system which is able to scale out for the sake of performance.

I've gone through the official document of RabbitMQ Clustering. However, its clustering doesn't seem to support scalability. That's because only through master queue we can publish/consume, even though the master queue is reachable from any node of a cluster. Other than the node on which a master queue resides, we can't process any publish/consume.

Why do we cluster then?

Comment: I resovled this problem using loadbalancer
look :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650061/how-to-make-rabbitmq-scalable/36747717#36747717

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we cluster then?

- To ensure availability.
- To enforce data replication.
- To spread the load/data accross queues on different nodes. Master queues can be stored on different node and replicated with a factor < number of cluster nodes.

> Other than the node on which a master queue resides, we can't process
>   any publish/consume.

Client can be connected on any node of the cluster. This node will transfer 'the request' to the master queue node and vice versa. As a downside it will generate extra hop.

Comment: To enhance throughput, can original copies of data which are logically supposed to reside on a single queue be spread across multiple nodes? Is that what you're saying? Btw, thanks for your kind answers.

Comment: You may achieve some kind of load balancing using [federated queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-queues.html). You can too achieve load balancing on the client side: producers publish messages to an exchange with a routing key suffix which rotates according to the load balancing factor (eg. key.0, key.1, key.0 .... for two queues). On the server side, you bind these two queues to this exchange using binding key `key.0` and `key.1`. These queues are managed by two dedicated nodes. Consumers consumes from theses 2 queues....

Comment: So, even though the node that is dealing with a request is mirrored and is a slave, the request is directed to a master queue, right?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot isnt sharding better than defining different queues on cluster nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question in the title `Is RabbitMQ Clustering including scalability too?` - yes it does, this is achieved by simply adding more nodes/removing some nodes to/from the cluster. Of course you have to consider **high availability** - that is queue and exchange **mirroring** etc.

And just to make something clear regarding:

> However, its clustering doesn't seem to support scalability. That's
>   because only through master queue we can publish/consume, even though
>   the master queue is reachable from any node of a cluster.

Publishing is done to exchange, queues have nothing to with publishing. A publishing client publishes only to an exchange and a routing key. It doesn't need any knowledge about the queue.