# How does RabbitMq clustering help scalability?

Tags: rabbitmq, scalability, high-availability

I want to build scalable RabbitMq system. I have gone through its [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650061/how-to-make-rabbitmq-scalable) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766513/is-rabbitmq-clustering-including-scalability-too). it seems clustering with HA-mirrored queues contradicts scalability as adding more nodes deteriorates performance.

I mean, If I have clustered system of (let's say) 3 nodes, how can clustering (without HA policy enabled) help increase throughput 
as opposed to having a system with 3 disconnected node?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the requirement for clustering?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is correct - clustering is for reliability, not additional throughput. This is true whether or not HA policies are in effect.

Comment: if we have cluster of 2 or more nodes with non-mirrored queues and no synchronization between them, doesn't it help in increasing throughput compared to one node?

Comment: No, why would it? Queues can only live on one node. The only added benefit is that producers and consumers could connect to either node and have access to the queue. Note that connecting to a node that does not "own" the queue involves an extra network hop to interact with the queue.

Comment: It does not increase throughput of a _single_ queue, but it does increase capacity globally. A queue is effectively rabbitmq's unit of concurrency. A single queue on a single machine will have a throughput cap that you'll have a hard time getting around. Multiple queues split among multiple rabbitmq nodes will have more resources (specifically, CPU) for each queue, however, which can help.